# R shiny app: Couldn't normalize path in `addResourcePath`

Tags: r, shiny

When I try to run my .Rmd document I get an error :

Output created: /tmp/RtmpIJCtdZ/file443d7655998c.html
Warning: Error in value[[3L]]: Couldn't normalize path in `addResourcePath`, with arguments: `prefix` = 'mathjax-local'; `directoryPath` = '/usr/lib/rstudio-server/resources/mathjax-26'
122: stop
121: value[[3L]]
120: tryCatchOne
119: tryCatchList
118: tryCatch
117: shiny::addResourcePath
116: shinyHTML_with_deps
115: 
99: doc
98: shiny::renderUI
97: func
84: origRenderFunc
83: output$**reactivedoc**
3: 
1: rmarkdown::run

I have tried to update all packages and run , still it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Using the environment it was created in using renv() was the solution. Looks like the issue was with updated packages.